# How to keep a Python app running?

Tags: python, automation

My problem is that i want to keep a Python app running, but it stops every 2-3 days. Is there a way to autorestart the .py when it stops. Is there a way to monitor that? Probably there is but i can't find it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't any reason why a python app should suddenly stop running. I would suggest looking into why it stops (crash, out of memory, ...) and trying to solve that.

If you really just want to restart it tough it depends on how you start it in the first place.

If you for example start it as a systemd service you should set the `Restart=on-failure` property in your systemd unit file.

If you just start it using the commandline you can use a simple bash loop:

```sh
while true
do
    python file.py
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did the Restart=on-failure option. I guess i have to wait a few days to see if it's really keeping the app running. :)

Comment: The app did not start correctly. So i did the second option. Worked for me!! And BTW it's an app that scans websites on demand but some sites make the app crash. That's why ;)